# How to pass user id to map activity from list adapter?

Tags: android

How to pass the id showed in toast to another map activity?

Friends list:

[image: Friends list]

Map activity:

[image]

i have done this code in ListAdapter

```
btnLocate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stringID=getItem(position).getID();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Friend ID"+stringID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent mapScreen = new Intent(context, MapActivity.class);
            mapScreen.putExtra("ID",getItem(position).getID());
            context.startActivity(mapScreen);

        }
    });
```

And this code in MapActivity.java

```
@Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String response;
            Intent listScreen= getIntent();
            Log.d(MainActivity.LOG_TAG,"UID List1"+ listScreen.getStringExtra("ID"));
            String body = "UID=" + listScreen.getStringExtra("ID");
            Log.d(MainActivity.LOG_TAG,"UID List2"+ listScreen.getStringExtra("ID"));
            response = http.postRequest(HttpConfigs.URL_COORDINATES, body);
            return response;
        }`
```

Comment: What do mean by *another map activity Friends list* ? You are doing it fine  for current MapActivity.

Comment: i think you should get your ID from Creation method of your MapActivity first and then use it in your AsyncTask . your code looks fine.

Comment: @Waseem Are you not getting ID in MapActivity or is it coming wrong?

Comment: @Dharmbir Singh i am getting this id in friends fragment and want to pass to MapActivity

Comment: Is your AsyncTask class part of your MainActivity class (inner class) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a instance variable named 'recievedID' in your MapActivity and then can fetch the ID and store it into that instance variable.

Example of fetching the ID in onCreate method of your `MapActivity` like:

```
private String recievedID = ""

onCreate(...){
    Intent listScreen= getIntent();
    String recievedID = listScreen.getStringExtra("ID");
    ...
}
```

Using it in your AsyncTask:

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String response;
        String body = "UID=" + recievedID;
        Log.d(MainActivity.LOG_TAG,"body = "+ body);
        response = http.postRequest(HttpConfigs.URL_COORDINATES, body);
        return response;
    }
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter class try to create your public interface like:

```
public interface ListItemClickListener {
  void onItemClicked(int position);
}
```

Then inside your Adapter class do also:

```
ListItemClickListener listener;
```

Then inside your existing ListListener put:

```
listener.onItemClicked(itemId);
```

Where itemId is something you get from that click listener.

Now you have to go to your Activity and implement your interface. This will generate an override method `onItemClicked(int position) {}` .
Inside this method you can get your id.

```
@Override
private void onItemClicked(int position) {
  this.position = position;
}
```

Now once you select an item on list and press it, it will trigger also the Activity‘s method and at that time you will get the `itemId`.